# ContextTextType and TableName for LinqDataSource when data source is List<string>

Tags: asp.net, linqdatasource

I have a LinqDataSource defined like this:

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" OnSelecting="LinqDataSource_FileSelecting"></asp:LinqDataSource>
```

In LinqDataSource_FileSelecting, it returns/sets a `List<string>` to e.Result, where e is the EventArgs (LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs) in the Selecting event of the LinqDataSource.  I'm getting this error when the page loads:

"The ContextTypeName property of LinqDataSource 'LinqDataSource1' must specify a data context type."

Based on this message and looking at the docs, I need to set the ContextTypeName and TableName properties of the LinqDataSource.  ContextTypeName would normally be the name of a class, and TableName would be the name of an enumerable property within that class.

When the data source is a `List<string>` I'm not sure what ContextTypeName or TableName I can assign.  I've tried `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>` for the ContextTypeName, but that didn't work, I received "Could not load type '`System.Collections.Generic.List<string>`'"

I realize the LinqDataSource may not be the appropriate control when the data source is a `List<string>` generated within the Selecting event.  But is there a ContextTypeName and TableName I can set for this scenario?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the answer.  Turns out that you can omit ContextTypeName and TableName when using the Selecting event and assigning a `List<string>` to e.Result.  However, if you assign `null` to e.Result, then this error will occur since ASP.NET doesn't know the type of data.  My code on the Selecting event was designed to set a non-null value to e.Result, but a separate problem was leading to null being set to e.Result ... leading to this error.